# RichTextBox changing Font Color using CFM_COLOR code

Tags: c#, colors, richtextbox, windows-forms-designer

I am developing a text editor in Windows Forms, for which I use RichTextBox widget. I came across a problem where, when selecting different styled text pieces, the selection would return a null value, which prevented me from, let's say, changing the size of a text that has parts of Verdana and Arial in it.

To solve this problem I created a new class that manipulates CHARFORMAT structure, and sends messages according to the style I want to change. Now I need to make a function that changes the font color of the user selection. For that, I need the CFM_COLOR tag, which I have no idea what it is, and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

```cs
    [Browsable(false)] 
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public Color SelectionFontColor
    {
        set
        {
            CHARFORMAT cf = new CHARFORMAT();
            cf.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(cf);
            cf.dwMask = CFM_COLOR;
            // There might be some missing code
            ???
            SendMessage(Handle, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, ref cf);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [RichTextBoxConstants.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBoxConstants.cs,9c6920e0788f8a6c) at referencesource.microsoft.com:

```
internal const int CFM_COLOR               = 0x40000000;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I came across a problem where, when selecting different styled text
>   pieces, the selection would return a null value

I cannot reproduce your problem : for example, I select text with differents styles, and I colorize in Orange the selected text with  *richTextBox1.SelectionColor*
=>

[image]

Comment: I guess I expressed myself poorly. The color can always be changed correctly, because it doesn't need any information from the selected text. But since I created functions to change font face, size, etc.. which overcome the problem of different styles, I decided to create one for changing font color, just for coherence. Thank you!